# Is it true that the Symmetry Principle could be generalized?

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*, the Symmetry Principle goes:
[image]
where $\Omega=\Omega^+\cup \Omega^-$, $I=\Omega^+\cap \Omega^-=\Omega\cap\text{the real axis}$, and $\Omega^+$ and $\Omega^-$ are the reflection of each other over the real axis.

The proof uses the Morera's Theorem, for any triangle in $\Omega$, subdividing it into small triangles that are contained in either $\Omega^+$ and $\Omega^-$ and using a continuity argument to conclude that the integral along each small triangle is zero, concluding that the integral along their sum is zero.

It seems that using Cauchy's Theorem that $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ in a simply connected region where $f$ is holomorphic, the argument can be applied to arbitrary $\Omega$, where the dividing $\Omega=\Omega^+\cup \Omega^-$ has nothing to do with the real axis and the shape of $I=\Omega^+\cap \Omega^-$ becomes arbitrary, for example $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$, $\Omega^+=\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ and $\Omega^{-}=\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{D}$. Therefore we have a far more powerful conclusion, that is

> Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic functions in $A$ and $B$ respectively where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets sharing part of their boundaries $I=\bar A\cap \bar B$. If $f$ and $g$ extend continuously to $I$ and
> $$ f(z)=g(z)\ \ \ \text{for all } z\in I $$
> then the function $F$ defined on the interior of $\bar A\cup \bar B$ by
> $$ F(z)=\left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> &f(z)\ \ \ \ \ \  \ &z\in A\\
> &f(z)=g(z)&z\in I\\
> &g(z)&z\in B
> \end{aligned}\right.$$
> is holomorphic.

I wonder if this conclusion is true. If it is, then I wonder that why the book restricts the discussion on that specified $\Omega$'s. I suppose that's because that the book introduces this Symmetry principle only to prove Schwarz Reflection Principle?

Comment: I'm not sure this generalization is right. For example, if $I$ is a curve which is not smooth, there is no reason to expect that $F$ would be holomorphic at the non-smooth points. And even if $I$ is smooth, there might be problems, since smoothness is weaker than holomorphicity.

Comment: assuming $I$ is locally a rectifiable curve, the result is easy to prove using Cauchy theorem; the main point is that points in $I$ must have a small neighborhood "half" contained in $A$ and "half in $B$, separated by $I$ - the result above excludes for example points that are not interior ( two disjoint triangles head to head at a common vertex is such an excluded case) but one still has to be careful with other possible weird points, so i would understand this theorem in the $I$ nice enough sense

Comment: @Conrad Well I did say that $F$ is defined on the interior of $\bar A\cup \bar B$, but yes there are other possible weird points. For example $I$ may not be a curve but has a point near which it is a three forks, and thus $I$ might consist of a helix jointed to another curve. The center of the helix is obviously a weird point. At least we have that the conclusion holds for $I$ being common shapes such as circles, and there needs to be nothing to do with the real axis.

Comment: Yes that's the idea for the general result; there are a lot of stronger theorems for regular shapes like circle arcs and segments where weaker conditions allow reflection in them similar to the classical case of the real axis